# req.isAuthenticated in passportjs keeps expiring after local-passport strategy login

Tags: node.js, passport.js, kraken.js, passport-local

Just ran into weird scenario - `req.isAuthenticated()` keeps invalidating me after I logged in with passport-local strategy on my local development.  The time varies in invalidating my login, but happens within the first 10 secs.

im using

```
"passport-local": "~0.1.6",
"passport": "~0.2.0",
```

with `krakenjs`

Ive set up the local strategy provided through this guide [krakenjs passport](https://github.com/lmarkus/Kraken_Example_Passport).  Its been running fine for the entire month till now. After restarting the computer, the symptom went away.  Would like to hear you guys out on this issue or any possible ways to avoid this - dont want this to ever happen in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a session issue. how do you store your session?

Comment: i use `req.session.user`, i do `req.session.user = null` when to invalidate the session